# Visited URLs in links in quotes on META site are hard to read

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta

URL links in quoted text in general on Meta.SFF.SE are a somewhat hard to read pink color.

But when a link is **visited**, it's a pale red that's extremely hard to read against the quote's pale gray background.

Examples:

> This is [Not visited link](http://no.such.url.I.am.sure.of.it.com)
>
> This is [Visited link - text seems hard to read](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/)

<sub>NOTE: I'm color naming challenged, so the names used for 2 colors in this post may be incorrect</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I have darkened the blockquote color significantly for better contrast. the change will roll out in the next production build.